# How to force Jinja templating on Airflow variable?

Tags: airflow

The [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html%20%22testing) say: `You can use Jinja templating with every parameter that is marked as “templated” in the documentation`. It makes sense that specific parameters in the Airflow world (such as certain parameters to `PythonOperator`) get templated by Airflow automatically. I'm wondering what the best/correct way is to get a non-Airflow variable to get templated. My specific use case is something similar to:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from somewhere import export_votes_data, export_queries_data
from elsewhere import ApiCaucus, ApiQueries

dag = DAG('export_training_data',
          description='Export training data for all active orgs to GCS',
          schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2018, 3, 26), catchup=False)

HOST = "http://api-00a.dev0.solvvy.co"
BUCKET = "gcs://my-bucket-name/{{ ds }}/" # I'd like this to get templated

votes_api = ApiCaucus.get_votes_api(HOST)
queries_api = ApiQueries.get_queries_api(HOST)

export_votes = PythonOperator(task_id="export_votes", python_callable=export_votes_data,
                              op_args=[BUCKET, votes_api], dag=dag)
export_queries = PythonOperator(task_id="export_queries", python_callable=export_query_data,
                                op_args=[BUCKET, queries_api, export_solutions.task_id], dag=dag,
                                provide_context=True)
```

Comment: Note that today, as of Airflow 1.10.4, op_args of PythonOperator *is already templated*. "{{ ds }}" should be replaced for you automagically. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.4/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The `provide_context` argument for the `PythonOperator` will pass along the arguments that are used for templating. From [the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.PythonOperator):

> **provide_context** (*bool*) – if set to true, Airflow will pass a set of
>   keyword arguments that can be used in your function. This set of
>   kwargs correspond exactly to what you can use in your jinja templates.
>   For this to work, you need to define **kwargs in your function header.

With the context provided to your callable, you can then do the interpolation in your function:

```
def your_callable(bucket, api, **kwargs):
  bucket = bucket.format(**kwargs)
  [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside methods(execute/pre_execute/post_execute, and anywhere you can get the Airflow `context`) of an Operator:

```
BUCKET = "gcs://my-bucket-name/{{ ds }}/" # I'd like this to get templated

jinja_context = context['ti'].get_template_context()
rendered_content = self.render_template('', BUCKET, jinja_context)
```